# Unity Android versions support?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Where can I get the list of Unity software versions along with a list of their supported versions of Android (APIs)? I can't find any official documents for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: [API Levels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html)

Seems like 2.3.1 is the minimum.

Added screenshot for different API versions: [image: bottom left]
Bottom left.

Comment: This is for the latest Unity software. I want **all** the Unity software versions (Unity 4, Unity 3...)

Comment: You have a button for history revisions of the scripting api, button left

Comment: What button? Take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I havent found a table that lists all Unity Versions and supported Android SDKs, but i have noticed in 5.6.0f3 Release Notes :

> System Requirement Changes:  Android minimum version supported updated
>   to 4.1 (JellyBean)

If you install the predecessor 5.5.6 Android Veriosn 2.3.1 to 6.0 are avaialbe in the player settings.

[image]